# Event/method to override to perform operations before binding in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to perform AOP operations on view models that is being binded in the views. I've read some concepts and examples on MVVM. I noticed the use of DataTemplate which listens to ViewModel changes and performs the binding automatically.

I'd like to perform some initializations on the view model before binding, how can I do this with WPF/MVVM?

Thanks.

Ways of binding. . .

Through data context

> ```
> view.DataContext = viewModel;
> ```

Through contents and templates

> ```
> <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SampleViewModel}">
> <vw:SampleDisplayView />
> </DataTemplate>
> ```

i'd like to intercept the view and viewmodel and initialize them before binding occurs.

Update:
I was able to intercept the view model through DataContextChanged event. Now I need the view to be initialized as well.

Comment: Do you want to intialize it before binding execution?

Comment: Yes :) I want to perform operations before it binds it in views, either by DataContext or Templates

Comment: Can you provide a theoretical example...not real sure what you mean. Before a single property is bound...well that happens by way of not setting the DataContext until you are ready...again confused on the question.

Comment: Ok will edit the description.

Comment: Just initialize your ViewModel in the ViewModel constructor?

Comment: in the getters of the properties in the viewmodel you can check if the private property is still null and depending on that initialize your value. but more information please

Comment: thanks, i ended up initializeing the ViewModel in the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this. I implemented ViewLocator as most toolkits have this.

ViewLocator is implemented through attached behavior, having me to look for the viewmodel and do initializations before assigning it to the datacontext.